# RewriteRules for two cases where the base path must be changed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help creating two Rewrite rules for two similar cases. I need to change the "base" path is the URL matches what I need it to match.

1.
So this would be my directory structure:

```
|- Library
|-- Plugins
|- app
```

So when the URL is

```
http://example.com/app/Plugins....(other things here)
```

I need to replace it to this:

```
http://example.com/Library/Plugins... (maintain params here)
```

---

2.Similar to the case above, I need a rewrite for this structure:

```
|- app
|-- Library
|--- Plugins
```

From:

```
http://example.com/app/Plugins....(other things here)
```

To:

```
http://example.com/app/Library/Plugins....(other things here)
```

---

For the first case I have tried working with the following rewrite, but unsuccessfully:

```
RewriteRule plugins/(.*) Library/plugins/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Yeah the **from** is the same in both cases.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. I will use them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example #1:

```
RewriteRule ^/app/Plugins/(.*) /Library/Plugins/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

For example #2:

```
RewriteRule ^/app/Plugins/(.*) /app/Library/Plugins/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```